# Unable to start selenoid server using docker

Tags: selenoid

1. `404 page not found` is displayed while accessing selenoid on `http://localhost:4444/` address
2. I am able to access the selenoid UI on 'http://localhost:8080/#/' address

content of docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'
services:
  selenoid:
    image: "aerokube/selenoid"
    network_mode: bridge
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
    volumes:
      - "$PWD:/etc/selenoid/" # assumed current dir contains browsers.json
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
  selenoid-ui:
    image: "aerokube/selenoid-ui"
    network_mode: bridge
    links:
      - selenoid
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    command: ["--selenoid-uri", "http://selenoid:4444"]
```

### Expected

That's it! You can now use Selenoid instead of Selenium server. Specify the following Selenium URL in tests:

```
http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
```

### Actual

`404 page not found` is displayed while accessing selenoid on 
 `http://localhost:4444/` address

Answer (score 0):

This is an expected behavior, there is no handler for `/` in Selenoid in latest release (only `/status` or `/ping`). Added welcome message in https://github.com/aerokube/selenoid/pull/804 because a lot of people are asking just the same question.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add

```
environment:
      command: ["-conf", "/etc/selenoid/browsers.json", "-log-output-dir", "/opt/selenoid/logs"]
```

See:
https://github.com/aerokube/selenoid/blob/master/docs/docker-compose.adoc

After that should works...